# SAPUI5 DatePicker dynamic InitialFocusedDateValue on sap.ui.table

Tags: javascript, sapui5

For instance I have a table which consist of Start and End dates. How could I possibly dynamically (optimize way) set the  InitialFocusedDateValue so that each time the user opens a datepicker, the previous date he chose will be the Focused date.

[image]

I've already tried the following but none worked:

1. Calling the navigate event to set InitialFocusedDateValue but this is being called after the pop up has rendered. So the new InitialFocusedDateValue doesn't take effect the first click.
2. Binding > not possible since it takes Date object.
3. Assigning Ids to the controls and calling by Id > doesn't work too.

I've thought of looping through the table and assigning to each datepicker aggregation the InitialFocusedDateValue everytime a date is chosen but obviously this is a crappy approach. Hope there's an optimal way of resolving this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set InitialFocusedDateValue for the Start Date depending on the End date of the previous row:

- Add an onChange event to the DatePicker
- Get the value and row index of the currently changed date.
- Check if there is a index+1 row, if yes get the content (controls) and give InitialFocusedDateValue the value from the event.

If you need to set End Date based on start date:

- Add an onChange event to the Start Date DatePicker
- Get the value in event callback
- Add assign it: `event.getSource().getParent().getContent()[indexOfEndDateControl].setInitialFocusedDateValue(dateValue)`

Comment: First scenario will not work if your current row is beyond the visible row count since getIndex will return the real row index. So if I am in row 35 and check table.getRows[](35), it will return undefined since I only have visible row count of 10.